# How to Control JSF form submitting? Primefaces commandButton

Tags: java, jsf, jakarta-ee

I have the following form, that I would like to submit only with my p:commandButton, however, I am getting submission in all my input boxes, how do I submit a form on p:commandButton only?

```
<h:form>
            <p:panel header="Lista de Referências" id="panel">
                <h:panelGrid columns="2" cellpadding="5">

                    <h:outputLabel>Referência</h:outputLabel>
                    <p:inputText value="#{entradaProdutoController.referencia}" 
                                 onkeypress="if (event.keyCode == 13) {onchange(); return false; }"> 
                        <f:ajax event="change" 
                                render="textDescri" 
                                listener="#{entradaProdutoController.listener}"/> 
                    </p:inputText>

                    <h:outputLabel>Descrição</h:outputLabel>
                    <h:outputText id="textDescri" value="#{entradaProdutoController.replyWith}" /> 

                    <h:outputLabel>Quantidade</h:outputLabel>
                    <p:inputText size="5" value="#{entradaProdutoController.quantidade}" />

                </h:panelGrid>
            </p:panel>
            <p:commandButton value="Adicionar" update="printTable" actionListener="#{entradaProdutoController.addAction(event)}">
            </p:commandButton>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tired the above suggestions with no successful results, so as a workaround this is what I am doing, this is probably not a best practice but it works(the hammering way of doing this):

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8' ?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
      xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
      xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui"
      xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
      >
    <h:head>
        <title>Facelet Title</title>
    </h:head>
    <h:body>
        <h1>Adicionar Referências</h1>
        <h:form id="formID" onkeypress="if (event.keyCode == '13') {return false;}">
            <h:outputLabel>Referência</h:outputLabel>
            <h:inputText  id="referenciaLoookup" value="#{testController.referencia}"
                          onkeypress="if (event.keyCode == '13') {document.getElementById('formID:testeButton').click()}"
                          > 
            </h:inputText>

            <h:inputText value="#{testController.referencia}" 
                         onkeypress="if (event.keyCode == 13) { onchange(); return false; }">
                <f:ajax event="change" listener="#{testController.teste(event)}" />
            </h:inputText>


            <p:commandButton id="lookup" value="lookup"
                             actionListener="#{testController.listener(a)}"/>

            <p:commandButton id="adicionar" value="Adicionar" 
                             actionListener="#{testController.addAction(e)}">
            </p:commandButton>

            <p:commandButton id="testeButton" value="teste" style="visibility: hidden;"
                             actionListener="#{testController.teste(event)}"/>
        </h:form>
    </h:body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2):

I believe that `onchange()` method is causing the page to be submitted when enter is pressed, if you don't want that behavior try removing...

```
onkeypress="if (event.keyCode == 13) {onchange(); return false; }"
```

Comment: if I remove it I have no way to a product lookup that is the whole idea behind using that code, however I don't want to submut the whole form just that field